# jQuery - get character pressed - REGARDLESS of Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I am trying to retrieve the character inserted into a textfield/input with jQuery.

I use the usual:

```
var character = String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode || e.which );
```

method, but the only problem occurs when I use a different keyboard layout which I just noticed.

So for example, on a Standard US Keyboard it works perfectly. On a German Keyboard for instanece, if I have the language set to English - basically rendering it a standard US Keyboard, when I press the characters equivalent to `:;'\,./[]=-`, I get the German characters I actually see on my keyboard (although the English equivalent of then is added to the input).

Example: if I `console.log( character )` for the folowing sentence I get:

- In the input: `[]\';/.,`
- In the console: `ÛÝºÞÜ¼¾¿`

My obvious question is, how can I make sure to get the true character inserter?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The keypress event is different from the keyup and keydown events as it contains the key actually pressed. Try using that instead. Check it out with this snippet:

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
  console.log('keypress', String.fromCharCode( e.which ));
});
$('body').keyup(function(e){
  console.log('keyup', String.fromCharCode( e.which ));
});
```

Comment: keypress event not firing in android browsers

Comment: Using arrow keys yields unexpected results.

Comment: @Stanly did you found any solution around this. I am facing this same issue.

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is making the character appear in a hidden textbox and fetch the actual value. That way, you will get the *character*. You are currently passing the *key* code as if it is a *character* code. They are not the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/RQQpT/

```
(function() {
    var input = $("<input>").appendTo('body') // an hidden input element
                            .css({ position: "absolute",
                                   left:     -500,
                                   top:      -500       });

    $('body').bind({ keydown: function(e) {
                         input.focus(); // make characters appear in input element
                     },

                     keyup: function() {
                         var value = input.val(); // get value when key pressed

                         input.val(""); // reset value of input element

                         if(value) {
                             alert(value); // if there is a value, display it
                         }
                     }
                  });
})();
```

Comment: That's a bit elaborate when you can reliably get the character typed in the `keypress` event.

Comment: @Tim Down: You're correct, but `keypress` does not work for characters which can be obtained with multiple keys, e.g. `ë` (which is `"` and `e`). `keypress` will fire `"` and `e` separately.

Comment: Do you have an example I could try on my UK keyboard? I'm pretty sure in your example most browsers will fire a keypress event with the eventual `ë` character in all browsers, but I'm not so sure whether you'll get other keypress events first.

Comment: @Tim Down: This code also fires for the `"`, but because the input is empty at that time yet, no alert is being shown. I'm afraid I've not much experience with other keyboards, and I cannot find an example after setting the keyboard settings to UK.

Comment: If you try typing into something like http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html you'll see exactly which key events get fired.

Comment: @TimDown keypress event does not work for chrome in android